# "Не щадя живота своего" - обособляем?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Как воспринимаете: "не щадя живота своего" - идиома? Обстоятельственное значение (образ действия)?  Или же надо обособлять без отговорок? Я эту запятую с наскоку влепил, а потом засомневался. Контекст - живая разговорная речь, интонация, как понимаю, вроде бы немного ироничная, но с некоторой обидой.

*Я пять лет боролась за права человека(,) не щадя живота своего, а тут вдруг меня обвиняют (в том-то и том-то).*

Понятно, что оба варианта можно мотивировать, но хочется понять, как воспринимается носителями русского именно в контексте.

Comment: >> *Контекст - живая разговорная речь, интонация, как понимаю, вроде бы немного ироничная, но с некоторой обидой.* Это, конечно, шедевр. Тут еще многое зависит от выражения лица говорящего. А может, и от тембра голоса. Не останавливайтесь на достигнутом!

Comment: @Niemand по теме, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое субъективное восприятие (с учетом всех изложенных в вопросе обстоятельств): автор иронично использует "не щадя живота своего" именно как идиому; запятая не нужна.

**Я пять лет боролась за права человека не щадя живота своего, а тут вдруг меня обвиняют (в том-то и том-то).**

Answer (score 1):

Идиома, фразеологизм, обстоятельство (*как?* а не *что делая?*).

Народ (который в теме) сплошь и рядом обособляет, и я тоже (независимо от интонации. А ирония вовсе ни при чём, она погоды не делает.)

Впрочем, есть правило, когда подобные штучки (сомнительные) обособляются всегда - если оне расположились между подлежащим и сказуемым:

*Я пять лет, не щадя живота своего, боролась за права человека...*

---

> Или же надо обособлять без отговорок?

И... не-понял-юмора-в-чём-дело, - почему **отговорок**-то?! *Оговорок,* то есть не оговаривая отдельные случаи.

Comment: *Впрочем, есть правило, когда подобные штучки (сомнительные) обособляются всегда - если оне расположились между подлежащим и сказуемым* - вот это реально интересно, не припомню... хотя и не наш случай. Источник найдете? Именно деепричастие/оборот, даже в значении образа действия?

Comment: *И... не-понял-юмора-в-чём-дело, - почему отговорок-то?!* - это не обсуждается. ***Отговорка**. ссылка на вымышленное или несущественное обстоятельство с целью уклонения, отказа от чего нибудь* (вики)

Comment: По сути. Если это идиома, похоже, то она выступает только в функции одиночного наречия, тесно связанного по смыслу со сказуемым, т.е. обстоятельства образа действия.

Comment: Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты могут не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания). Ср.: Благодаря дождям посевы зазеленели. – Посевы, благодаря дождям, зазеленели; Во избежание утечки газа отключен кран. – Отключен, во избежание утечки газа, кран; Он сделал это в силу привычки . – Он, в силу привычки , сделал это; Согласно приказу группа расформирована. – Труппа, согласно приказу...

Comment: *с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями* - Где здесь производный предлог или предложное сочетание?

Comment: А я и не говорю про "здесь". Цитата иллюстрирует "подобные штучки".

Comment: Понятно))) Вы хоть предупреждайте тогда, что не на вопрос отвечаете, а просто поговорить захотелось.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами, обособляются независимо от места, занимаемого ими в предложении:**
   Вернувшись в каюту, он долго не мог заснуть (Л. Соболев);
   Говорил он осторожно, опасаясь сказать что- то лишнее (М. Горький);
   Подъехав к лесу, Хаджи-Мурат остановился и, забрав много воздуху в легкие, засвистал и потом затих, прислушиваясь (Л. Толстой).
2. **Деепричастные обороты не обособляются:**

   ~**если оборот** (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) **тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания:**

   ***Бьются русские солдаты не щадя живота своего*** (С. Алексеев);

~**если оборот представляет собой фразеологизм:**
 На другой день в школе я еле досидел до конца уроков и побежал домой сломя голову (В. Драгунский);
 Тоже вот Данилушка пошел было к тебе в гости, да не солоно хлебавши воротился (Д. Мамин-Сибиряк).
( *Н.В Адамчик. Самый полный курс русского языка - Минск, Харвест, 2008* )

1. Примеры:
   Ежедневно в течение 20-30 минут прорабатывайте все мышцы брюшного пресса, **не щадя живота своего.**
   Шакира танцевала в «Олимпийском», **не щадя живота своего**.
   На присяге перед строем я сказал: «**Не щадя живота своего**, выполняйте свой долг!».

"В бурном море людей и событий,
**Не щадя живота своего**,
Совершите вы массу открытий,
Иногда не желая того".

2. Примеры:
   **Не щадя живота своего** от смеха.  Авторский вечер Михаила Жванецкого.
   ВЕСЬ В ТРУДАХ!
   **Не щадя живота своего** отбираю у бедных и отдаю богатым!
   **Не щадя живота** **своего** защищали Родину.

*"но хочется понять, как воспринимается носителями русского именно в контексте"*?

В контексте получается, что **народ-то обособляет, но не сплошь и рядом**.

Comment: *В контексте получается, что народ-то обособляет, но не сплошь и рядом.* - Вы не на тот вопрос ответили. Вы лично воспринимаете как идиому и образ "действия" или как обычный деепричастный оборот?

Comment: Вы меня сейчас запутаете! Я  ответила на часть Вашего вопроса  "Или же надо обособлять без отговорок?". Надо, но с оговорками... А высказывать свое мнение - по поводу идиомы или деепричастного оборота - не решаюсь.  Мне хватило "интонационного" направления на пятый курс филфака.

Comment: Для деепричастного оборота - первая часть правила; для идиомы - если оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) - вторая. Это моё личное ,"народное" мнение, как носителя языка без филологического образования.

Comment: *А высказывать свое мнение - по поводу идиомы или деепричастного оборота - не решаюсь.* - так правила я мог бы и сам посмотреть, кабы не знал. Суть такая, что на мой взгляд идиому можно трактовать как обстоятельство, неразрывно связанное со сказуемым (это обсуждаемо). А вот с обычным деепричастным оборотом у меня не получается. Вот это, собственно, и хотелось бы уяснить. Я совсем не против, когда тут все правила  методично приводятся (читаю-то не только я), но я-то ищу вывод, а не посылку.

Answer (score 0):

Фразеологизм "не щадя живота своего" имеет значение "смело, самоотверженно" (стиль высокий), но  в современном языке часто приобретет ироничный оттенок. Оборот  чаще **обособляется** (в обоих случаях), несмотря на свой фразеологический статус.

Это можно объяснить его **распространенностью**: такой оборот сложно вписать в структуру предложения без обособления.

Но всё-таки такие варианты существуют, например:  "Я вместе со своими сыновьями поклялся **не щадя животА своего** защищать Литву".  Здесь пауз нет, оборот выделен логическим ударением.

Приведенный пример также можно отредактировать: **Не щадя животА своего** я пять лет боролась за права человека,  а тут вдруг меня обвиняют (в том-то и том-то). Здесь также можно обойтись без паузы, выделив оборот логическим ударением.